# Why is Pool slower than the same number of Processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I recently tried refactoring some parallel processes into a pool and was surprised that the pool took almost twice as long as pure processes.  Please assume they are running on the same machine with the same number of cores. I hope that someone can explain why my implementation using Pool is taking longer and perhaps offer some advice:

Shared dependency:

https://github.com/taynaud/python-louvain

```
from community import best_partition
```

Here is the faster implementation using `Process`.  [UPDATE] refactored to control the number of active processes same as the Pool implementation, still faster:

```
processes = []
pipes = []

def _get_partition(send_end):
    send_end.send(best_partition(a_graph, resolution=res, randomize=rand))

for idx in range(iterations):
    recv_end, send_end = Pipe(False)
    p = Process(target=_get_partition, args=(send_end,))
    processes.append(p)
    pipes.append(recv_end)

running_procs = []
finished_procs = []
while len(finished_procs) < iterations:
    while len(running_procs) < n_cores and len(processes):
        proc = processes.pop()
        proc.start()
        running_procs.append(proc)

    for idx, proc in enumerate(running_procs):
        if not proc.is_alive():
            finished_procs.append(running_procs.pop(idx))

for p in finished_procs:
    p.join()

partitions = [pipe.recv() for pipe in pipes]
```

And here is the slower, `Pool` implementation. This is still slower no matter how many processes the pool is given:

```
pool = Pool(processes=n_cores)
results = [
    pool.apply_async(
        best_partition,
        (a_graph,),
        dict(resolution=res, randomize=rand)
    ) for i in range(iterations)
]
partitions = [res.get() for res in results]
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: In the first example, you're creating potentially way more processes.

Comment: Thanks for replying Shadow, I was running them on the same machine and the pool was using the max number of cores that the machine had to offer.

Comment: What exactly is included in your measure of time? The entire code snippet in both cases or portions of them?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Try bumping up the number of processes you're creating in the pool - you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Shadow I will try that, thank you.

Comment: @roganjosh - entire in both cases

Comment: Also, we are talking about multi _processing_ right? You've tagged this as multithreading which is handled differently in Python.

Comment: Ah thanks, will change the tag.

Comment: I significantly bumped the number of processes in the pool however it made no difference at all.  And I also tried a version with Process that allows a limited number to run at a time and this is still faster than Pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when there is a difference between a pool and bunch of processes (it can be for the benefit of either), it is your data set and task performed that define the outcome.

Without knowing what your `a_graph` is, I make a wild guess it is something big. In your process model, you rely on the in-memory copy of this in your subprocesses. In your Pool model, you transmit a copy of `a_graph` as an argument to each worker every time one is called. This is in practice implemented as a queue. In your process model, your subprocess gets a copy of this at C level when Python interpreter calls `fork()`. This is much faster than transmitting a large Python object, dictionary, array or whatever it is, via a queue.

The reverse would be true if tasks took only a minuscule time to complete. In this case, Pool is the better performing solution, as Pool passes tasks to already running processes. Processes do not need to be recreated after each task.  In this case, the overhead needed to create a lot of new processes that run only a fraction of a second, slows the process implementation down.

As I said, this is pure speculation, but in your examples there is a significant difference what you actually transmit as a parameter to your workers, and that might be the explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes sense.